# Printer not accessible by saned, probably udev rules not working

Tags: usb, printing, scanner, udev, hplip

I'm trying to setup a printer as network printer with a server. `sane-find-scanner` outputs `could not open USB device 0x03f0/0xc111 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions) could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error` If ran sudo'd the output changes to `found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [HP], product=0xc111 [Deskjet 1510 series]) at libusb:001:003 could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error`

Similar results with `scanimage -L` only with elevated privileges the printer is found

As far as I can tell the user saned is not able to access this usb device. I already added the user saned to the groups scanner, lp and plugdev as recommended in several guides. Also tried to change the users as which saned will be run to `ubuntu` name of my ssh login user.

I also tried to add my own udev rules. Added:

`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c111", GROUP="scanner"`

to `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-hp.rules`

Checking with

`udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/*)`
the custom made rule file parses without any errors.

Additional Information:

The printer and scanner works, as far as I can tell. Running `sudo hp-setup` sees and configures the printer correctly, so I can print and scan with it. But only with elevated privileges.

Don't know if this is odd, but running `sudo systemctl restart saned` yields `Failed to restart saned.service: Unit saned.service is masked.` and can't be unmasked. Not quite sure if this is expected behavior but maybe because `saned.socket` will start and stop this service as needed?

I already set everything up to announce all connected devices to my home network. Other PCs can see the scanner already, but trying to do anything will result on a crash on the client side. Therefore the server must see something to broadcast the scanner to the network. But I don't know how.

Anyone has an idea why it's not working? I'm trying to solve this for weeks even completely rebuild the server to avoid the interference of any old configurations, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have something that works, but not sure if its the right way. The device is owned by root (0). Adding the Tag `OWNER="saned"` in my custom udev file overrides the ownership. Now I can access the printer/scanner both with `sane-find-scanner` and `scanimage -L`. Can anyone confirm this approach? If so I can will document my findings and close the question.